# Angular Differential loading - How to generate only one polyfill.js file

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9

We just migrated from angular 7 to angular 9. My application targets to larger audience and i need to support legacy browsers like IE-11. Hence i have made the following change in tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

The target is set to

```
"target": "es5",
```

which will target to legacy browsers as mentioned [Here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#local-development-in-older-browsers) which will generate the build artifacts as folows

[image]

But if you see carefully, there are two polyfills that are gernerated,

```
chunk {2} polyfills.js (polyfills) 46.5 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} polyfills-es5.js (polyfills-es5) 129 kB [initial] [rendered]
```

But i want to generate only one polyfill which supports both modern and legacy browsers. **Is there any way to generate only one polyfill (polyfills.js) file like how it used to happen before angular 8+ ?**

Comment: Why do you want only one polyfill? It's better to let the client browser download the most appropriate one

Comment: I have a constraint where i do not use the angular generated index.html rather i havemy own over the backend. In that i cannot include two polyfills as we have some packaging constraints.

Comment: You can't add a task that just takes the correct polyfill? Or that deletes  `polyfill.js` after the build ?

Comment: Thats what i am doing currently. Just wanted to know if there is a way around.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: the solution below is a bit hacky and I'd recomment going with some post build process to remove the files that you do not want.

To have the build the way it was before angular 8, i.e. completely remove differential loading (even for polyfills), you need to:

- set `target` to `es5` in your `tsconfig.json` file
- comment all the queries in your `browserslist` file, normally located at the root of your project
- install `core-js` node module
- Add core-js imports to your `polyfill.ts`, like the awy it was in angular 7

**Note**: deleting the `browerslist` file does not work, as it'll still generate 2 polyfill bundles

**browserslist** file

```
# You can see what browsers were selected by your queries by running:
#   npx browserslist
#> 0.5%
#last 2 versions
#Firefox ESR
#dead
#IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
```

**polyfill.ts**

```
/****************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Comment: Hmmm but ie10-11 related polyfills are not added by this solution !!!1

Comment: The app doesnt load in IE !

Comment: @VikhyathMaiya I updated my answer. I tried on a really simple project and it does work

Comment: yeah i known this will work. But since from angular 9, angular is supposed to handle the core js dependencies right. So there is no way of creating single polyfill js without adding core js as a dependency ?

Comment: Not that I know of

Comment: Just a follow up question .. is installing install core-js node module necessary ? Core-js is bundled as part of angular now right ?

Comment: Also if i dint add the dependency, it seems to be be not working !

Comment: Yeah it's part of angular, but if you want to use it explicitly I think you need to install it

Comment: Okay thanks :) I thought angular would bundle all core-js polyfills as part of the build. Turns out it bundles only some because of thich my signalR client is failing in IE11. Sadly core-js@3.6 is also not working with the same. Seems like i have to go back to core-js 2 to make it work